# differential equation, bit off more than i could chew

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I started down the path of a project for school that was inspired by mythbusters.  The oritinal thought was showing why a bullet will effectively cease effectiveness past a given depth.  So I'm rocking $F_d = \frac{1}{2}pv^2AC_d$ which we can effectively compress down to $F = Kv^2$ as the rest for my purposes will be constants.  Applying newton's laws to this we turn it into $y' = a / y'' = a$ making $F=ma = my''$, after a little help from a friend we arrive at $y'' = \frac{F}{m} = \frac{K}{m}(y')^2$. Letting $\alpha=\frac{K}{m}$ thus collapsing the problem finally down to $y'' = \alpha(y')^2$

This is the crux of my problem.  Can anyone explain the approach to solving this?  Seems this is a little beyond the calc II course this was originally for.  But seeing as I'm already neck deep in the problem in other ways, I see no point in giving up on it now.

Comment: Start by solving $v'=v^2$ with $v=y'$.

Comment: Assume $u(t)=y'(t)$ then your equation becomes $u'(t)=\alpha u^2(t)$, ie $du/u^2=\alpha dt$ which means quickly $-1/u(t)=\alpha t +A$ where A is a constant. Finally, $u(t)=-1/(t+A)$ and you have to solve a new ODE: $y'(t)=-1/(t+A)$.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the method is called "Reduction of order": The basic idea: Take $y^\prime = z$ and insert it into your equation s.t.
$$
z^\prime = \alpha z
$$
And solve this as an ODE. Then simply compute $y$ from $y^\prime = z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to 
$$\left(\frac{1}{y'}\right)'=-\alpha,$$
which means that $1/y'=-\alpha t+C$ or $y'=-1/({\alpha t-C})$. Next, integrate once more to get
$$y(t)=-\int\frac{dt}{\alpha t-C}=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln(\alpha t-C)+D,$$
where $C$, $D$ are two arbitrary constants of integration.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain what made him unhappy?